# Jquery dialog confirmation to a specific a href link with php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pop up a jquery confirmation dialog when i press to delete an item from my database, the code above is inside a `while($records=mysql_fetch_aray)` so i have several records:

```
echo"<tr>
    <td>".$registo["id_produto"]."</td>
    <td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($registo["pic"])."' width='80' height='80'></td>
    <td>".$registo["nome"]."</td>
    <td>".$registo["preco"]."</td>
    <td>".$registo["quantidade"]."</td>
    <td>".$categoria."</td>
    <td>".$registo["descricao"]."</td>
    <td>".$registo["cura"]."</td>
    <td>".$registo["aroma"]."</td>
    <td><a href='deleteProduto.php?id={$registo["id_produto"]}'><i class='fa fa-times'></i> Delete</a></td>
    </tr>";
```

When i press the "delete" button i wanted to pop up a jquery confirmation dialog with a "yes" and "no" and when pressed yes go to "deleteProduto.php" with the respective id of the item i want to delete.

I've searched about this but only finded this working with a form and i only want it to work with the 'a href' link with the respective "id".

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how your code is working at all without tons of warnings and errors.

I think you propably didnt notice it, because you did it correctly in the rest of the code but

```
"...?id={$registo["id_produto"]}'>...";
```

is definetely no proper string composing. It hast to be

```
"...?id=".$registo["id_produto"]."'>...";
```

Comment: It is all working, this is only the partial code of my page.

Comment: If everything works, why are you searching for help?